# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object. Многопоточный парсинг

Tags: python, многопоточность, парсер, selenium

Посидел я около 5 часов пытаясь решить все сам, но никак. Я видел что вопросы на эту ошибку уже есть, но как-то я ничего не нашел полезного. Вот вообщем код:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

import lxml.html
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from pathlib import Path
from loguru import logger

import time
import re
import csv
import random
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

from browser import Browser


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)


class Parser(Browser):

    """ Этот класс представляет парсер """

    def __init__(self, link):

        self.link = link
        self.browser = self.get_browser()
        self.start_parsing()


    def convert_to_bs(self):

        """ Получить объект BeautifulSoup """

        page = self.browser.page_source
        page = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

        return page


    def start_parsing(self):

        """ Процесс парсинга """

        self.launch_browser(self.link)
        self.parse_responses()


    def parse_responses(self):

        """ Парсинг вопросов """

        global get_content

        def get_content(answer):

            """ Достаем содержимое ответа """

            content = answer.find('div', {'class': 'answercell'}) \
                .find('div', {'class': 'js-post-body'}).text

            return content


        def get_all_answers():

            """ Получаем все ответы с вопроса """

            page = self.convert_to_bs()
            all_answers = page.find('div', {'id': 'answers'}) \
                .find_all('div', {'class': 'answer'})

            return all_answers


        # НИЖЕ ВЫЗОВ ФУНКЦИЙ

        all_answers = get_all_answers()

        print(list(pool.map(get_content, all_answers)))
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from pathlib import Path


class Browser:

    """ Класс представляющий браузер """

    def get_browser(self):

        """ Настроить и получить браузер """

        user_agent = UserAgent()
        user_agent = user_agent.random
        driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')
        options.add_argument(f'--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
        #options.add_argument('--headless')

        browser = webdriver.Chrome(
            driver,
            options=options
        )

        return browser


    def launch_browser(self, url, time=5):

        """ Запустить браузер """

        self.browser.get(url)
        self.browser.maximize_window()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(time)


    def close_browser(self):

        """ Закрыть браузер """

        self.browser.quit()
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Импорты бы получить

Comment: @handowl, обновил вопрос

Comment: Нашёл аналогичный вопрос на английском SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021254/maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-multiprocessing-and-bs4